# Getting TypeError: partitions is undefined in partitions.js file of aws sdk while getting secrets from aws

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, aws-secrets-manager, aws-sdk-js

I am using @aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager in my frontend application to get the secrets from aws secret manager but I am getting "TypeError: partitions is undefined" error.

This is the code I am using.

```
    import {
        SecretsManagerClient,
        GetSecretValueCommand,
    } from "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager";
    
    async function getAWSSecrets() {

        const client = new SecretsManagerClient({
            region: "my-region",
        });

        const command = new GetSecretValueCommand({
            SecretId: "my-aws-arn",
        });

        try {
            const response = await client.send(command);
            console.log("Console response ", response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error retrieving secret:", error);
        }
    }

    getAWSSecrets();
```

The version of @aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager is latest(3.337.0)

How can I fix this ?